# The probability of choosing topics

Tags: probability

We have 5 discussion topics and 5 students and would like to have one discussion leader for each topic. If students randomly and independently select their topic, find the probability that there is exactly one topic with- out a discussion leader.

My solution is:

1.Choose one topic to be without a discussion leader, that is choose 1 from 5, equals to 5.
2.Let the 5 students select the topics other than the above one, that is (4/5)^5.
3.Multiply the result of 1 and 2, that is 5*(4/5)^5.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Not quite.  You need to ensure there is *exactly* one topic not discussed; not more and not less.

Count the ways to:

- Select the topic not to be discussed.
- Select two people to double up on one topic.
- Select the topic they choose.
- Select topics for each of the three remaining people (without repetition).

That's the size of your favoured space out of all $5^5$ (equally probable) possibilities.

---

Alternatively. There are $(4^5- 4\cdot 3^5 + 6\cdot 2^5-4)$ ways five people can select *exactly* four of four topics, by the *Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion*.   Multiply *this* factor by the count of ways to select the topic not-discussed.

Comment: So let me have a try:

Comment: So let me have a try:

1. Select the topic not to be discussed. That is choose 1 from 5, equals 5.
2. Select two people to double up on one topic. That is choose 2 from 5, equals 10.
3. Select the topic they choose. That is choose 1 from 4, equals 4.
4. Select topics for each of the three remaining people (without repetition). That is 3!, equals 6.

Multiply the above results, that is 5*10*4*6=1200, then divide it by 5^5=3125, the probability is 1200/3125=0.384.

Is that OK?

Comment: @ Emily. That's right.